# How to transfer data between view controllers without creating object of secondview

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

```
Firstview *first = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstview"];
first.fetchalldata = dicdata;
first.fetchfunction = [self urlstr];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:first animated:YES];
```

I am transfer data like above code but i dont want to use that method so what can i do??

Comment: You will have to explain what you're trying to do. Where is this code? Is it inside a method? What method?

Comment: Actully i am using TabBarController in my app but the problem is that i cant show TabBarControl in my view when i transfer data from one view to another THROUGHT TABBARCONTROLLER.    I have a Navigationcontroller-->Viewcontroller--->TabBarController-->SecondViewController

Comment: So what are you trying to do? I'm struggling to understand what is not working. Is `self` a `UITabBarController`? If so, it shouldn't have a `navigationController`. Can you explain a bit more (in your question) about what you are trying to do. At the moment we just have code that is not doing what you want but we don't know what you actually want. What does the user of the app do to make this happen? What is the desired outcome?

Comment: My main problem is that i cant show tabbarcontroller in my secondview I did an example of TabBarControll and itz working properly but when i implement in my project i fail todo

Answer (score 0):

In term of OOP, transfer data in your current way is the right thing to do. But if you want another solution, I can suggest but not recommend:

- Make a singleton - DataStore or something like that.
- Use NSUserdefault.